# How to give path to .exe in PowerShell if path has dependency on .conf file?

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have a windows service running and the path to executable is given like (right click on service -> Properties ->Path to executable)

```
"abc.exe" -s "cdf.conf"
```

I am trying to automate installing this service with powershell.How should i give the full service .exe with conf file?

***$abcService = "?????"***

```
$Proc = Start-Process $abcService $exeArgs -WorkingDirectory "D:\abc\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

How should i give input to .exe with -s to config file ? Any help ? or suggestions? Could be a minor one but its toatlly new to me.

I'm trying to run it as a service.

This is what i was doing

```
$abcservice = "D:\abc\abc.exe"
$abcserviceName = "abc"



function InstallABCservice(){   
Write-Host "Installing $abcserviceName"
$argList = "/s D:\abc\abc.conf"
$Proc = Start-Process $abcservice $argList -WorkingDirectory "D:\abc\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "Install running under process id $($Proc.Id). Waiting 5 seconds"
Start-Sleep -s 5
if ($Proc -ne $null){
    Stop-Process -Id $Proc.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

Write-Host "Install should be complete. Checking for service $abcservice"
$abcsvc = gwmi win32_service -filter "name='$abcserviceName'"
if ($abcsvc -eq $null) {
    throw "Service $abcserviceName does not exist. The automated install process failed. A manual install will be required"
}
Write-Host "Found service $abcserviceName. Changing startup-type to Disabled"
Set-Service $abcserviceName -startuptype "Disabled"
$abcsvc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null)
Write-Host "Startup-type changed to Disabled"
Write-Host "Install successfully complete. Service $($abcsvc.DisplayName) installed and startup type set to Disabled"
```

}

```
function Main(){        
InstallABCservice
```

}

```
Main
```

Comment: Tried , I am updating my whole scenario

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to automate the start a process with some arguments; then you could do the following:

```
$service = "c:\path\abc.exe";
$arguments= "/s c:\test\myconf.conf"
$proc = Start-Process $service $arguments -WorkingDirectory "D:\abc\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

If you're looking to register your services (so it appears under services.msc or get-services) so you can use start-service/ stop-service cmdlets, then you need to register the service first :

To register an exe as a service (windows) :

```
sc.exe create <new_service_name> binPath= "<path_to_the_service_executable>"
```

To unregister / uninstall a service:

```
sc delete <servicename>
```

For more information about installing / handling services : 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599.aspx

If you've installed an exe as a service; you operate it by get-service, stop-service, start-service and restart-service.

Get-service will give you the status of a running service.

Hope this explains what you need; as your question is ambigious

Comment: I am not sure it worked or not but definitly this helped , so after doing this i am still not able to see my service in services.msc section

Comment: Is this a services or a process? If it's a services that's installed (where you can see it under services.msc) you can start and stop it using Start-Service and Stop-Service ; you shouldn't use Start-Process

Comment: You can use "Get-service" to see what services are installed. In combo with start-service and stop-service for starting and stopping them.

Comment: Updated my answer to support for services and installing them, with references to how to get, install and uninstall exe-files as services .

Comment: Check my updated answer for how to install / remove and operate services.

Comment: I am familier with start , stop and other services command , if i used Start-Service then how can i make my service to use configuration from .conf file , thats my doubt is ?

Comment: You can't. The arguments are registered to the service upon service installation/registration. If you are to dynamically change this every time you start the service; then you will have to uninstall and reinstall the service with the new arguments) - see the links I provided on how to do this. Alternatively, you point to the same configuration file everytime and before you start the service; you replace the content in the configuration file with the "new" content/configuration.

Comment: yes you are right , so while doing installation what should be my path since i told you on checking the similar service klind of service in mstsc i found the path to executable is given like this "abc.exe" -s "cdf.conf" , how should i get the equivalent while doing Start-Service in powershell ?